# how to keep UIImage size not change,but change it's file size

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage

i want to keep the UIImage width and height not change,but change the UIimage file sizeI used :

```
NSData *uploadpic = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photoData, 0.5);

   int compressionQuality=0.5;

   while (uploadpic.length>500000) {

       compressionQuality=compressionQuality+0.1;
       if(compressionQuality>=1){
           compressionQuality=1;
       }

       UIImage *tempImg=[UIImage imageWithData:uploadpic];
       uploadpic = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(tempImg, 0.5);
       NSLog(@"uploadpic = %d", uploadpic.length);
   }
```

but the uploadpic all ways is 630297 not change,how to do

EDIT: i modify the the

```
NSData *uploadpic = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(tempImg, 0.5);
```

as

```
UIImageJPEGRepresentation(tempImg, compressionQuality)
```

all is ok.

but i have a question:why set a fixed value 0.5 ,it is not changed. every time change 0.5 why not correct?

Comment: You are not using compressionQuality anywhere ?

Comment: Please read [**this**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006894-CH3-SW9) **clearly** may be it`s help you to decrease size of image.

Comment: `int compressionQuality=0.5;` Doesn't make much sense. You're creating an `int` and then passing it a `double` which in this case will be rounded up to 1. Then `compressionQuality=compressionQuality+0.1;` will also evaluate as 1 because 1.1 will be rounded down.